# RestTemplate getting 403 Forbidden while request via Postman or Curl works fine

Tags: java, spring-boot, resttemplate

I am using RestTemplate to call an external service which is obviously developed with php. I am a user of this service and have no control over it to change any configurations. When I call the service with a GET request using Postman, I get the correct response. But when trying to call the service with RestTemplate within a Spring Boot application, like this:

```
String response = restTemplate.exchange(
                    SERVICE_URL_INCLUDING_TOKEN,
                    HttpMethod.GET,
                    null,
                    String.class).getBody();
```

I get this error:

```
You don't have permission to access this resource
```

I tried setting the user agent manually like this:

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
headers.add(
    HttpHeaders.USER_AGENT,
    "Mozilla/5.0 Firefox/26.0"
);

HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(null, headers);

String response = restTemplate.exchange(
                    SERVICE_URL_INCLUDING_TOKEN,
                    HttpMethod.GET,
                    entity,
                    String.class).getBody();
```

Now I get a different custom response with status 302:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>302 Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Found</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="https://api.example.com/apijson.php?token=xxxxxxxxxxxx">here</a>.</p>
</body></html>
```

This is not an error but definitely not the json response I was expecting. I noticed when sending the request with Postman a cookie `PHPSESSID` with a value like this `bt1d4ea1cdd6afb49b0cca7a94ecb493` is set automatically in the header. But I have no clue how to get this cookie using restTemplate. Unfortunately the support staff of the external service are not also very helpful and couldn't help.
any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: Strange, has that API moved? or changed ? with any Authorization or contract changes ? We may have to check that

Comment: Unfortunately the owner has no idea. looks like someone developed it for them and left. But As I said the same call with Postman works just fine.

Comment: Seems like movement of resource, check this out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/302

Comment: The problem was https instead of http. They had http in the documentation but it had to be https.